# igraph in R - to know the centrality

Tags: r

While using igraph in R, I plotted a graph from 30 students to courses they are taking in a particular semester. What code should I use to know the centrality of the graph, i.e. which is the central subject that maximum students are taking.
vertices include - students and courses
edges - student to course if they are taking it

code used

```
C2 <- dplyr::select(C_long, Names, Courses)
Table1 <- table(C2$Names, C2$Courses)
C5 <- as.data.frame.table(Table1)
names(C5) <- c("from", "to", "count")
C5$count <- ifelse(C5$count == "0", NA, C5$count)
C6 <- na.omit(C5)
V1 <- dplyr::select(C3, Courses)
V1 <- unique(V1)
V1$group <- "course"
V2 <- dplyr::select(C3, Names)
V2 <- unique(V2)
V2$group <- "Student"
names(V1) <- c("id",  "group")
names(V2) <- c("id", "group")
V <- dplyr::bind_rows(V1, V2)
g <- graph.data.frame(C6, directed=TRUE, vertices=V)
plot(g,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold, edge.arrow.size=0.3,  vertex.size=15)
```

Comment: 1) your code is useless to us because we don't have your data. 2) search for "centrality" in the R help and there's a demo in the igraph package and functions that compute centrality measures.

Answer (score 0):

Course node with highest degree should be the one. All you have to do is obtain the degrees of the subject nodes. In addition, you can actually plot the differential sizes of the nodes based on their degree to have a graphical picture.

Comment: by the way, why don't you simply obtain the mode of subject to represent this stat? Why go the network way??